# Simplifying Colors on Canvas

Tags: javascript, colors, rgb

My end goal is to have two version of an image, the first is the basic default image, but the second should be a *simplified* version of the first, using only basic colors.

I would like to change all the ranges of red for example to `(255, 0, 0)`. I have tried manually adding in ranges of red but just for that one color there were about 20 different statements. I would like to know how anyone would go around doing this. I have looked into [color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) and that seems pretty relevant and useful.

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

[image: Colors simplified]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up [colour quantisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization).

Comment: Show some attempts so that we may be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have found a suitable answer to my question.

I have solved my question by calculating the 'color distance' of each pixel. I then loop over my default colors and compared the distance for each of them. I then check which 'distance' is the lowest. The color that is the closest to my default color is the closest match.

The equation that I used to calculate the color distance was the following:

```
Math.sqrt( Math.pow((r1 - r2), 2) + Math.pow((g1 - g2), 2) + Math.pow((b1 - b2), 2));
```

- Thanks to Amadan for the tip about color quantization.